# Remove last , in PHP generated MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have the following PHP script:

```
$i = 0;
        while ($i < 30){
            $insertquery = "INSERT INTO {$savename} VALUES (";

            foreach ($valuearray as $column){
                $insertquery .= $column[$i] . ",";
            }

            $insertquery .= ");";
            echo $insertquery;
            $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, $insertquery);
            if ($queryResult === TRUE){

            }else{
                print "<br /><br />No Row created. Check " . mysqli_error($con);
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

The $valuearray is a two dimensional array with everything that needs to be inserted into the table.
The issue is that the above code creates a MySQL statement in the form

```
INSERT INTO rates_test VALUES (1000,0.1,2.3,100,2,3,);
```

Which gives a Syntax error as the last value has a `,` after it.

How could I go about changing the script so that the last value does not have a `,` after it, or prehaps delete it after the foreach loop?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: The only people that will access this will be the owners of the database anyway, doing injections would not be in their interest for sure. But you are right and the code will be changed before release

Comment: no, only the people INTENDED to access this will be the DB owners ;) while someone may not get access to your server/mysql, they may get in to something, through a vulnerability in code for example...

Comment: It doesn't matter what your intentions are, or where you're planning to deploy the code. Once you've written it there's no telling where it'll go. These little mistakes have a way of coming back to haunt you in the future (The Little Internal Tool That Grew Up) so it's best to never make them in the first place. Plus, do you want to have to fix this later when someone says they can't insert a name like "O'Malley"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before `$insertquery .= ");";` you could use `$insertquery = rtrim($insertquery, ',');`

My preferred method for building `IN` lists though is to use `implode`:

```
"VALUES (" . implode(',', $valuearray) . ")";
```

It's also worth noting that you should preferably be using parameterized queries.  I'm not sure whether you can bind a variable number of arguments using `mysqli`, but in PDO the idea would be something like:

```
"VALUES (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($valuearray), '?')) . ")";
```

This emits `"VALUES (?,?,?)"`.  Then you could just pass `$valuearray` to `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function so you don't have to worry about the last comma

```
$insertquery .= implode(",", $valuearray);
```

PS: Seems the code is prone to SQL injection if the array comes from user input

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not put it there in the first place if possible, than add something you don't want then remove it later (each to their own I guess):

```
foreach ($valuearray as $column)
  {
    $insertquery .= $column[$i];

    if ($i < 29)
      {
        $insertquery .= ",";
      }
  }
```